# Pytest: How to redirect logs to console and tmp file created using tmp_path fixture

Tags: python, logging, pytest, fixtures

I am writing one script using pytest  framework, where I need to redirect logs to console as well as temp file created by using fixture(tmp_path). I have written below code, file  is getting created but console logs or logs in files are not observed :

```
import os
import logging
from datetime import datetime

global LOG_FILENAME

script_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(__file__))[0]
LOG_FILENAME = datetime.now().strftime(script_name + "_%H_%M_%S_%d_%m_%Y.log")

def test_create_file(tmp_path):
    d = tmp_path / "Logs"
    d.mkdir()
    p = d / LOG_FILENAME

    p.write("content")
    logging.info(p.strpath)
    logging.basicConfig(filename=str(p), level=logging.INFO)
    logging.info(str(p))

    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    console.setFormatter(formatter)
    logging.getLogger("").addHandler(console)

    logging.info("This is log1 message")
    logging.info("This is log2 message")
    assert p.read_text() == "content"
```

The output I was expecting that my log1 and log2 message should be captured in log file which I created above as well as visible in console. But none of the requirement is fulfilled. 
Below is my output:

```
nishantsaha@ztphost:~/home/nishantsaha/tests$ python3 -m pytest -v test_tmpdir.py -s
========================================================== test session starts ==========================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-5.1.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
Test order randomisation NOT enabled. Enable with --random-order or --random-order-bucket=<bucket_type>
metadata: {'Python': '3.6.9', 'Platform': 'Linux-4.15.0-76-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic', 'Packages': {'pytest': '5.1.2', 'py': '1.8.0', 'pluggy': '0.13.1'}, 'Plugins': {'random-order': '1.0.4', 'json-report': '1.2.0', 'metadata': '1.8.0'}}
rootdir: /home/nishantsaha/tests
plugins: random-order-1.0.4, json-report-1.2.0, metadata-1.8.0
collected 1 item

test_tmpdir.py::test_create_file FAILED
```

Any pointers to what I am missing and how to solve this? If I am using same code but without fixture, in that case logs to file and console both are observed

Answer (score 0):

You need setup your logger("") level to `INFO` or below, setup handler level only isn't enough.

```
logging.getLogger("").setLevel('INFO')
```

By default logger's level is `WARNING`(30). The effective level is the intersection of your logger's level and handler's level, offered by `getEffectiveLevel()`.